# How to implement redirection to external site in Gatsby?

Tags: redirect, gatsby

How to implement in Gatsby one redirection from `/foobar/` to external url `http://example.com/page/`?

With Gatsby `2.20.6` this code don't work:

```
// gatsby-node.js

...

exports.createPages = ({ actions }) => {
    const { createRedirect } = actions;

    createRedirect({
        fromPath: '/foobar/',
        isPermanent: true,
        redirectInBrowser: true,
        toPath: 'http://example.com'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`createRedirect` gives other plugins the opportunity to generate redirects during your static site build. Depending on where you are actually hosting that static site, the process for making the redirects can be totally different.

[More background on the Gatsby `createRedirect` docs:](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/actions/#createRedirect)

> Server redirects don’t work out of the box. You must have a plugin setup to integrate the redirect data with your hosting technology

- [Plugin to create redirects for hosting on Netlify](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-netlify/)
- [Plugin to create redirects for hosting on Amazon S3](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-s3/)
- [Generic plugin to create redirects](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-meta-redirect/), which you could use to ex. generate a `ROUTER` file for [redirects on Surge.sh](https://surge.sh/help/adding-redirects), or make your own plugin

Hope that helps!